# Storing a length of 2-bit states in byte[knownsize]

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I've got an array of bytes:

```
byte[] myPool = new byte[100];
```

And I want to store strings consisting of 4 characters. Consider it as DNA:

```
- A = 00
- C = 01
- G = 10
- T = 11
```

How would I go about parsing and inserting a string of these characters as bytes? Not looking for code, really looking for something to read.

```
String example = "CGGGGT" //011010101011 aka 1707 aka 0x6AB
myPool.insert(example); //assume empty pool at start
```

Then I want myPool[0] to be 0x0006 and the record to start at myPool[2] (So as to be able to hold length indicators of up to 0xFFFF, which I also do not know how to enter into two separate bytes in the array)

myPool[2] should be 0x006A and myPool[3] should be 0x00B0 (last 4 bits will be 0000).

So what I really don't understand is how to "make" bytes in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bytes are actually a primitive data type, like `int`, rather than an object, like `String`. They store a number between -128 and 127, inclusive. You can create one like this:

```
byte myByte = 0;
```

And store it like this:

```
myPool[0] = myByte;
```

Remember that when you store the byte number `1`, its representation in binary will look like `00000001`. `2` will look like `00000010`.

Your biggest challenge is going to be packing four of those values (A C G T) into one byte. Your best bet there is going to involve using four operators:

- `&`, which is a bitwise AND. You can use it to only let through the bottom two bits, for instance.
- `|`, which is a bitwise OR. You can use it to combine new bits into an existing byte that you are building.
- `<<`, which is a shift left. It moves the value "left" by a certain number of positions, and is equivalent to multiplying by a power of 2.
- `>>`, which is a shift right. It moves the value "right" by a certain number of positions, and is equivalent to dividing by a power of 2.

Hope that helps, and if this is an assignment, good luck with it!

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely one of those cases where it's so simple it becomes confusing.

Since there can only be four values, each of them can be 2 bits. Now I'm thinking something like:

Comment: @Geofram I'm sorry, but the rest of your comment didn't come through, after "like:". Try again?

Comment: Yeah, it was all jumbled. The jist was, since there are 4 values, each can be 2 bits. I think I can left shift the byte 2 places to add a new value in behind the first and so on.

My remaining confusion is how do you put anything above 255 into 2 slots of a byte array? If I want 0xEA60 (60000 or 1110101001100000) into slots 0 and 1, how do I split them up and then retrieve it later?

Comment: @Geofram Same way! Use `value & 0xFF` to get one byte, then `(value >> 8) & 0xFF` to get the other.